# Gradient estimate of the eigenfunction of Laplacian on hyperbolic space

Tags: riemannian-geometry, sp.spectral-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, laplace-equation

I am trying to understand the asymptotic behaviors of the gradient of the eigenfunction function of the Laplace-Beltrami operator on the hyperbolic plane $\mathbb{H}^2$. Specifically, my focus lies on the equation $\Delta^{\mathbb{H}^2} u - 2u = 0$, where $u:\mathbb{H}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function. My question is as follows: Is there a constant $C > 0$ such that for all $z \in \mathbb{H}^2$,
$$\Vert\mathrm{grad}^{\mathbb{H}^2}u(z)\Vert \leq C \vert u(z)\vert.$$ Where $\Vert \cdot\Vert$ stands for the hyperbolic metric of $\mathbb{H}^2$.

The Schauder-type inequality for elliptic operators provides a local estimate, with the constant $C$ depending on the local neighborhood weather I'm looking for global estimate.